# Why is structure size always returning -1?

Tags: java, native, jna

I have created the following structure mapping it into a C structure.But when I print the size of the structure using CALCULATESIZE() it is always returning -1. Why is that?

Below is my java structure.

```
public class ipj_action extends Structure {

public long ipj_action_value;
Pointer p;

public ipj_action() {
    setAlignType(Structure.ALIGN_NONE);
    System.out.println("Structure size is  : "+CALCULATE_SIZE);
}

@Override
protected List getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("ipj_action_value");

}

}
```

Below is the main class where I call it.

```
public class RFIDMain {

    public  rfidlib rlib;
    public  ipj_iri_device ipj_iri_device;
    public  ipj_action ipj_action;
    public  ipj_error errorStatus;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    RFIDMain r = new RFIDMain();


    r.rlib = (rfidlib) Native.loadLibrary("rfidlib", rfidlib.class);
    r.ipj_iri_device = new ipj_iri_device();
    r.ipj_action = new ipj_action();
    r.errorStatus = new ipj_error();
    r.ipj_action.ipj_action_value = 0x1;

    r.errorStatus = r.rlib.start(r.ipj_iri_device, r.ipj_action);

    System.out.println(r.errorStatus);

}
```

Comment: What is CALCULATE_SIZE?

Comment: It is a method available in Structure class of JNA library. Please refer the tag jna.

Comment: This question is off topic for the `c` tag

Comment: thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @mayooran It doesn't seem to be a method. From the javadoc, `CALCULATE_SIZE` is a protected field of the `Structure` class. Maybe you are looking for [`calculateSize(boolean force, boolean avoidFFIType))`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#calculateSize(boolean%2C%20boolean))

Comment: Thanks that was a mistake. But calculateSize method is not visible in Structure class. How can I call it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`Structure.size()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#size--).

That method will fail if JNA cannot determine the structure size, which may happen if you've neglected to initialize any array fields or used a type which JNA cannot convert into a native equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing an integer constant `CALCULATE_SIZE`, (the Java style convention that constants are in all capitals is a clue there, as is the fact it's a variable not a method). You need instead to call the method `calculateSize`.

https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#calculateSize(boolean)

Comment: Thanks that was a mistake. But calculateSize method is not visible in Structure class. How can I call it??

Comment: It's package private, which means you need to be in the same package to see it. That also suggests you are not supposed to be using it unless you know what you are doing so you may want to revisit what you are doing and why you need this.